# Show infinite series is the limit of a Cauchy sequence in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, complete-spaces

Recall that $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$ is defined as the completion of the Riemann integrable functions on the real line with respect to the norm $||f|| = \int |f|$.

Let $h_n(x)$ be the real-valued functions which is equal to $0$ on $[0, 1-\frac{1}{2^n})$, $1$ on $[1-\frac{1}{2^n}, 1)$ and periodic with period $1$. Let $\chi_{[0,1]}$ be the characteristic function of the interval $[0,1]$.

Show that the infinite series 
$$
f(x) := \sum_{n=1}^\infty h_n (2^{n(n-1)/2} x) \chi_{[0,1]}(x)
$$
can be regarded as a limit of a Cauchy sequence in $L^{1}(\mathbb{R})$.

My attempt: It seems to be helpful to calculate $||h_n (2^{n(n-1)/2} x) \chi_{[0,1]}(x)||$ first.

$$
||h_n (2^{n(n-1)/2} x) \chi_{[0,1]}(x)|| \\
= \int_{0}^{1} |h_n (2^{n(n-1)/2} x)| dx
$$

Let $u = 2^{n(n-1)/2} x$, we have

$$
\int_{0}^{1} |h_n (2^{n(n-1)/2} x)| dx = 2^{-n(n-1)/2}\int_{0}^{2^{n(n-1)/2}}|h_n(u)|du
$$

From the property of $h_n(x)$, I should have $\int_{0}^{1}h_n(x)dx = 1/2^n$.
But I am stuck at how to proceed given this fact and also how do I know that $f(x)$ is the limit of some Cauchy sequence in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ after I evaluated the norm.

Comment: You can use the $n$th partial sum of the series as your Cauchy sequence. Thus it is beneficial to find the $L^1$ bound of the terms (then sum $n-m$ of them). In your integral just do a substitution so that $h_n$ takes $x$ as its input. $\int_0^1 h_n(x)dx$ has integral $1/2^n$ because it is equal to 1 on an interval of that length!!

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst I did the substitution, but could you give some hints on how to proceed and also how can I get the partial sum of the series?

Comment: $f_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}h_k (2^{k(k-1)/2} x)$ as your cauchy sequence. 

Then we bound $f_n(x) - f_m(x)$ in the $L^1$ norm. Use the triangle inequality on the $n-m$ resulting terms. Each one is an integral like you did.

Comment: for $\int_0^1 h_n(2^{n(n-1)/2}(x)dx$. Take $u = 2^{n(n-1)/2}x$.

We have $\int_0^{2^{n(n-1)/2}}h(u)2^{-n(n-1)/2}du = 2^{-\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}2^{-n}$

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Thanks! To clarify, the purpose to find the bound $f_n(x)-f_m(x)$ in $L^1$ norm is to show that $f_n(x)$ is a cauchy sequence?

Comment: yes that's right!

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Can I say that $\sum_{k=m+1}^{n} h_k(2^{k(k-1)/2}x) < \int_{0}^{1} h_n(2^{n(n-1)/2}x)dx$ and conclude that $f_n$ is Cauchy? Not sure how to apply triangle inequality in this case.

Comment: you integrate the LHS here. Then use triangle inequality to take the sum out of the integral.  Then you sum $2^{-n(n-1)/2}2^{-n}$.The sum tends to zero as $n-m\to 0$ as you'd expect.

Comment: What does Riemann integrable on $\mathbb R$ mean?